# Add suport for Chromium Embedded Framework to screen sharing

Tags: chromium-embedded

I'm developing a desktop application that shares the computer screen with other users over the internet.

The cef supports WebRTC technology and I'm trying to use it to screen sharing. Unfortunately cef does not support the capture of native screen. I followed some tutorials that show how to make changes to the source code of cef to share the screen, but no success.

The processes that follow are 1 and 2:

1- Settings (on windows) specified in: https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/MasterBuildQuickStart.md

2- Changes specified in: 
http://arkenthera.github.io/blog/Enabling-CEF-to-Screen-Share-using-getUserMedia-API/

In the process 2 occurred error to run patch.bat file located in chromium/src/cef/tools. Identified that the path of some specified files within the patch.bat was incoherent, I copied the patch.bat for chromium/src/cef and ran. In execution error occurred in allow_screen_sharing.patch file located in chromium/src/cef/patch/patches.

This topic (https:// bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/1065) in the CEF forum has some information on how to modify the cef to support screen sharing. Despite making changes, when I run cefclient with --enable - usermedia -screen- capturing flag and access  https:// html5-demos.appspot.com/static/getusermedia/screenshare.html to screen capture, i get the message requesting activation of the flag.

Someone worked with o cef to screen sharing and successful?
They know how to give this support to an application that uses the cef?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't solved it yet (otherwise, for other people with the same problem): I have recently made it work in both Chromium 53 and 54. You have to manually edit libcef/browser/browser_host_impl.cc with the changes in the patch file https://github.com/buglloc/cef-builds/blob/master/patches/allow_screen_sharing.patch

The line numbers have changed, so you will have to look for the code before/after each change. Just make the changes before the ninja build.

Comment: DennisJakobsen, I have made the patch, but it still shows black video stream. What kind of syntax are using to call it from javascript, what ChromeMediaSource and Id you are using? Thanks!

Comment: After applying the patch and building the browser try run the browser with the following arguments `--enable-media-stream --enable-usermedia-screen-capturing` I have tested and seen it working on https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/Pluginfree-Screen-Sharing/ It might be worth mentioning that I haven't used the guide you link to. I only applied the patch from github

Comment: Were you able to achieve this on Chromium 55 ?

Comment: Yes. Both for Cef and CefSharp